# How to define a rotates function

Tags: haskell

How to define a rotates function that generates all rotations of the given list?

For example: rotates `[1,2,3,4] =[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,1,2,3]]`

I wrote a shift function that can rearrange the order

```
 shift ::[Int]->[Int]

 shift x=tail ++ take 1 x
```

but I don't how to generate these new arrays and append them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following

```haskell
shift :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
shift l n = drop n l  ++ take n l

allRotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
allRotations l = [ shift l i | i <- [0 .. (length l) -1]]
```

yields

```
> ghci
Prelude> :l test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> allRotations [1,2,3,4]
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,1,2,3]]
```

which is as you expect.

I think this is fairly readable, although not particularly efficient (no memoisation of previous shifts occurs).

---

If you care about efficiency, then

```haskell
shift :: [a] -> [a]
shift [] = []
shift (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]

allRotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
allRotations l = take (length l) (iterate shift l)
```

will allow you to reuse the results of previous shifts, and avoid recomputing them.

Note that `iterate` returns an infinite list, and due to lazy evaluation, we only ever evaluate it up to `length l` into the list.

---

Note that in the first part, I've extended your shift function to ask how much to shift, and I've then a list comprehension for `allRotations`.

Answer (score 23):

Another way to calculate all rotations of a list is to use the predefined functions `tails` and `inits`. The function `tails` yields a list of all final segments of a list while `inits` yields a list of all initial segments. For example,

```
tails [1,2,3] = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3],   []]

inits [1,2,3] = [[],      [1],   [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

That is, if we concatenate these lists pointwise as indicated by the indentation we get all rotations. We only get the original list twice, namely, once by appending the empty initial segment at the end of original list and once by appending the empty final segment to the front of the original list. Therefore, we use the function `init` to drop the last element of the result of applying `zipWith` to the tails and inits of a list. The function `zipWith` applies its first argument pointwise to the provided lists.

```
allRotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
allRotations l = init (zipWith (++) (tails l) (inits l))
```

This solution has an advantage over the other solutions as it does not use `length`. The function `length` is quite strict in the sense that it does not yield a result before it has evaluated the list structure of its argument completely. For example, if we evaluate the application

```
allRotations [1..]
```

that is, we calculate all rotations of the infinite list of natural numbers, ghci happily starts printing the infinite list as first result. In contrast, an implementation that is based on `length` like suggested here does not terminate as it calculates the length of the infinite list.

Comment: "tails" is no longer supported in recent version of haskell .   

       <interactive>:30:1:  

       Not in scope: `inits'  

       Perhaps you meant `init' (imported from Prelude)

Comment: One need to first "import Data.List"

Answer (score 5):

```
shift (x:xs)  =  xs ++ [x]
rotates xs    =  take (length xs) $ iterate shift xs
```

`iterate f x` returns the stream ("infinite list") `[x, f x, f (f x), ...]`. There are `n` rotations of an `n`-element list, so we `take` the first `n` of them.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given so far work fine for finite lists, but will eventually error out when given an infinite list. (They all call `length` on the list.)

```
shift :: [a] -> [a]
shift xs = drop 1 xs ++ take 1 xs

rotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotations xs = zipWith const (iterate shift xs) xs
```

My solution uses `zipWith const` instead. `zipWith const foos bars` might appear at first glance to be identical to `foos` (recall that `const x y = x`). But the list returned from `zipWith` terminates when either of the input lists terminates.

So when `xs` is finite, the returned list is the same length as `xs`, as we want; and when `xs` is infinite, the returned list will not be truncated, so will be infinite, again as we want.

(In your particular application it may not make sense to try to rotate an infinite list. On the other hand, it might. I submit this answer for completeness only.)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to support rotation on an infinite stream *at all*, IMHO; it's just not a valid operation. In infinite input, your function simulates `tails` (`iterate tail`).

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the following solutions, using the built-in functions `cycle` and `tails`:

```
rotations xs = take len $ map (take len) $ tails $ cycle xs where
    len = length xs
```

For your example `[1,2,3,4]` the function `cycle` produces an infinite list `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2...]`. The function `tails` generates all possible tails from a given list, here `[[1,2,3,4,1,2...],[2,3,4,1,2,3...],[3,4,1,2,3,4...],...]`. Now all we need to do is cutting down the "tails"-lists to length 4, and cutting the overall list to length 4, which is done using `take`. The alias `len` was introduced to avoid to recalculate `length xs` several times.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be something like this (I don't have ghc right now, so I couldn't try it)

```
shift (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]

rotateHelper xs 0 = []
rotateHelper xs n = xs : (rotateHelper (shift xs) (n - 1))

rotate xs = rotateHelper xs  (length xs)
```

Comment: It's easier and more readable to just use `iterate` instead of a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

```
myRotate lst = lst : myRotateiter lst lst
  where myRotateiter (x:xs) orig
          |temp == orig = []
          |otherwise = temp : myRotateiter temp  orig               
          where temp = xs ++ [x]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
rotate l = l : rotate (drop 1 l ++ take 1 l)

distinctRotations l = take (length l) (rotate l)
```