# All list rotations in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have a function to rotate a list:

```
rotate :: [a] -> [a]
rotate [] = []
rotate (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```

Now I want a function that gives a list with every possible rotation of a finite list:

```
rotateAll :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

In a imperative language, I would do something like (in pseudocode)

```
for i = 1 to length of list
  append list to rotateList
  list = rotate(list)
```

Of course, thinking imperatively probably doesn't help me find a functional solution to this problem. I'm looking for some hints as to how to tackle this.

**Additional thoughts:**

To solve this, I have two issues to tackle. First I need to repeatedly rotate a list and collect each result into a list. So a first solution needs to do something like

```
rotateAll xs = [xs (rotate xs) (rotate (rotate xs)) (rotate (rotate (rotate xs))) ...]
```

Of course I don't know how many times to do this. I'd be satisfied to do this infinitely and then use `take (length xs)` to get the finite number of lists I desire. This actually demonstrates the second issue: determining when to stop. I don't know if using `take` is the most efficient or elegant way to solve the problem, but it came to mind as I was typing this and should work.

**Addendum:**
Now that I have found two solutions on my own or with hints. I will gladly welcome any other solutions that are faster or use different approaches. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the `iterate` function.

Comment: Be aware that you will be traversing the list once for each iteration (append is O(n), for n the length of the list) and once for calculating the length of `xs` (which is also O(n))

Comment: It might be interesting to note that you can solve this for infinite input lists, too - so long as you rotate the correct direction. Coming up with a solution that works well for both infinite and finite inputs is a good further exercise.

Comment: @TiloWiklund I usually want to first make a solution that works and tune for efficiency later. It's still good to keep these concerns in mind during an initial solution. So thanks for pointing it out! I'll revisit my `rotate` function if that becomes a concern later.

Comment: @Carl Hmmm...that's some food for thought. It seems that I would have to rotate an infinite list in the same direction as I am a finite list by taking the head off. However, I can't exactly append the head to the end of an infinite list...hmmm

Comment: @Code-Guru: You can append to the end of an infinite list, but semantically those two lists will behave exactly the same. That is, `ℕ ++ [1] ~ ℕ`.

Comment: @Vitus So `xs ++ ys` where `xs` is some infinite list won't hang in an infinite loop?

Comment: @Carl for infinite lists, rotations make little sense, as you cannot append to the end; see `tails` in `Data.List`.

Comment: @Code-Guru `xs ++ ys` is the same as `xs` when `xs` is infinite.

Comment: @sdcvvc So lazy evaluation means that nothing is actually executed to do this "append"?

Comment: @Code-Guru append is defined as `(x:xs) ++ ys = x:(xs ++ ys); [] ++ ys = ys`, when `xs` is infinite the second line will never fire.

Comment: @sdcvvc So it's pattern matching along with lazy evaluation. Gotchya.

Comment: Here's a cute hack to avoid calling `length`: `zipWith const (iterate rotate xs) xs`.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's interesting. I don't think it buys any efficiency gains, though ;-(

Comment: @Code-Guru Actually, it's quite important: this allows your function to be fully lazy (whereas `length` is strict). Try the version with `length` and the version with `zipWith` on an infinite list in ghci, and compare what happens.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm all about laziness!

Comment: @NormanRamsey yup, I realized that when Jan posted his answer. In fact, I flagged this thread myself. *lol*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from [iterate](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aiterate), you could write a function that generates a list of n rotations. Case n=0 would just wrap the input in a list and case n=m+1 would append the input to the result of case m. Although using standard functions is generally preferred, sometimes writing your own solutions is healthy.

Comment: Strangely, I basically used that same idea as I thought about this after I posted my question. I didn't know about the `iterate` function, so that will be added to my Haskell aresenal.

Answer (score 7):

Use the predefined functions in `Data.List`!  You can get a list of all rotations using four function calls, no recursion, and no `rotate` function.

You asked not to have a full solution posted here.  For those who want to see it, a full solution (one line of code) appears at http://pastebin.com/atGiw1ig.

Comment: Interestingly, this is the same solution in the link @Jan gave!

Comment: since it's been so long, I guess you should reveal your solution fully now. Very nice solution, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that is fully lazy in both the list of rotations itself and each individual entry in the list. The key is is that rather than pre-compute the length, just match up the elements in your result to the elements in the list as you go, stopping when your input list runs out.

```
rotations xs = map (takeSame xs) $ takeSame xs (tails (xs ++ xs)) where
    takeSame [] _ = [] 
    takeSame (_:xs) (y:ys) = y:takeSame xs ys
```

In addition this is much better behaved memory-wise than some of the other choices due to its use of tails and only the single concatination. Of course, it also handles infinite lists properly as well.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to consider this site [How to define a rotates function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631664/how-to-define-a-rotates-function/7632272#7632272) that answers the same question.

**Edit due to Comment:** The implementations based on `rotate` as well as the one based on `inits` and `tails` should be quadratic in the length of the list. However, the one based on `inits` and `tails` should be less efficient because it performs several quadratic traversals. Though note that these statements only hold if you evaluate the result completely. Furthermore, the compiler might be able to improve the code so you have to treat these statements with caution.

Comment: Hmmm...how does the run-time efficiency compare?

Comment: With the relatively recent improvements to `inits`, the `inits` and `tails` version should be asymptotically optional.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the complexity is still quadratic in the length of the argument because `++` is applied to lists of increasing length from zero to the length of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
rotations (x:xs) = (xs++[x]):(rotations (xs++[x]) )
```

this creates continues lazy rotations
now just take the first unique ones, which will be equal to the length of the original list

```
take (length xs) (rotations xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with two solutions. First is a hand-crafted one that came to me after I posted my question:

```
rotateAll :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotateAll xs = rotateAll' xs (length xs)
    where rotateAll' xs 1 = [xs]
          rotateAll' xs n = xs : rotateAll' (rotate xs) (n - 1)
```

The other uses @Tilo's suggestion:

```
rotateAll :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotateAll xs = take (length xs) (iterate rotate xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also generate them recursively. Generating all rotations of an empty or single element list is trivial, and generating the rotations of `x:xs` is a matter of inserting `x` into the correct position of all the rotations of `xs`.

You could do this by generating the indexes to insert into (simply the list [1, 2, ...] assuming the previous rotations are in this order) and use `zipWith` to insert `x` into the correct positions.

Alternatively you can `split` the rotations around the position using a combination of `inits` and `tails` and use `zipWith` to glue them back together.

Answer (score 1):

> Addendum: Now that I have found two solutions on my own or with hints.
>   I will gladly welcome any other solutions that are faster or use
>   different approaches. Thanks!

Since no else pointed out using `cycle` I thought I would add this solution for finite lists:

```
rotations x = let n = length x in map (take n) $ take n (tails (cycle x))
```

For an infinite list `x` the rotations are just `tails x`.

Evaluating the `cycle x` is O(n) time and space, each element of `tails` is O(1), and `take n` is O(n) time and space but the two `take n` are nested so evaluating the whole result is O(n^2) time and space.

If it garbage collects each rotation before lazily generating the next one then the space is theoretically O(n).

If you are clever about how much you are consuming then you do not need `map (take n)` and can just walk the `cycle x` or `take n (tails (cycle x))` and keep the space O(n).

Answer (score 1):

From scratch:

```hs
data [] a = [] | a : [a]

end :: a -> [a] -> [a]
end y []       = y : []
end y (x : xs) = x : y `end` xs

-- such that `end x xs  =  xs ++ [x]`

rotating :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotating [] = []
rotating xs = rots xs
   where
      rots xs@(x : xs') = xs : rots (x `end` xs')

-- An infinite list of rotations

rotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotations xs = rots xs (rotating xs)
   where
      rots []       _        = []
      rots (_ : xs) (r : rs) = r : rots xs rs

-- All unique rotations, `forall xs.` equivalent to `take
-- (length xs) (rotating xs)`
```

Or:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatters #-}

rotate :: [a] -> [a]
rotate []       = []
rotate (x : xs) = x `end` xs
   where
      end y []       = y : []
      end y (x : xs) = x : end y xs

iterate :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate 0 _ _ = []
iterate n f x = case f x of
                   x' -> x' : iterate (n - 1) f x'

length :: [a] -> Int
length xs = len 0 xs
   where
      len !n []       = n
      len !n (_ : xs) = len (n + 1) xs

rotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotations xs = iterate (length xs) rotate xs

-- Starting with single rotation
```

Or, integrated:

```hs
rotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotations [] = [[]]
rotations xs = rots xs xs
   where
      rots []       _            = []
      rots (_ : xc) xs@(x : xs') = xs : rots xc (x `end` xs')

      end y []       = y : []
      end y (x : xs) = x : end y xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `Data.List`

```
import Data.List
rotate x=[take (length x) $ drop i $ cycle x | i<-[0..length x-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following `rotations` function as a helper for my [permutations algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43507769/4543207). It seems to be the fastest among all here.

```
rotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotations xs = take (length xs) (iterate (\(y:ys) -> ys ++ [y]) xs)
```

Comment: How does this differ from my own solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11870855/1440565

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If you mean your second snippet with the `rotate` function yes it should be basically the same if the rotate function that you refer is in fact `\(y:ys) -> ys ++ [y]`. This (or these) seem to be the best way so far.