# Get all permutations of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do this from scratch, without the use of a library outside the standard lib. Heres my code:

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations (x:xs) = [x] : permutations' xs
    where permutations' (x:xs) = (:) <$> [x] <*> split xs
            split l = [[x] | x <- l]
```

The problem is that this only produces one fork of the non-deterministic computation. Ideally I'd want

```
(:) <$> [x] <*> ((:) <$> [x] <*> ((:) <$> [x] <*> ((:) <$> [x] <*> xs)))
```

But I can't find a way to do this cleanly. My desired result is something like this:

```
permutations "abc" -> ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: So you want permutations not combinations, right? Your function name seems to indicate the latter, but your example is definitely the former.

Comment: youre right, changed the questions.

Answer (score 42):

Maybe you should use existing code:

```
import Data.List
permutations [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 12):

For a simple implementation without considering duplications in the input

```
permutations :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
permutations [] = [[]]
permutations as = do a <- as
                     let l = delete a as
                     ls <- permutations l
                     return $ a : ls
```

Test:

```
λ> permutations [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
λ> permutations "abc"
["abc","acb","bac","bca","cab","cba"]
λ>
```

[Algorithm Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710713/algorithm-to-generate-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 10):

**TL&DR For faster code than Data.List.permutations, jump to Part II**

**Part I**

I am relatively new to Haskell but [I had developed a very efficient permutations algorithm for JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41068709/4543207). It  almost beats the heaps algorithm, yet in JS, rotating an array is more costly compared to lazy Haskell `iterate` function over the lists. So this one, unlike all the provided answers above seems to be much more efficient.

The built in `Data.List.permutations` is still like 2x faster than this one as of today since i don't know the performance constraints of Haskell at all. May be someone here could help me to push this code a little forward.

So I have a helper function which returns a list of all rotations of the provided list. Such as

`rotations [1,2,3]` would yield `[[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]]`

accordingly the perms function is;

```
rotations :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotations xs = take (length xs) (iterate (\(y:ys) -> ys ++ [y]) xs)

perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms []     = [[]]
perms (x:xs) = concatMap (rotations.(x:)) (perms xs)
```

**Part II**

So i have been thinking on how to make the above code more efficient. OK the lists in Haskell are linked lists and unlike JavaScript the length is not a property that you can access in O(1) time but O(n). It's a function traversing the whole damn list, basically counting all the items in the list. Hence very expensive if used repeatedly. That happens to be what exactly we do by `take (length xs)` instruction in each invocation of the rotate function. We literally invoke it millions of times if your input list is like 10-11 items or more in length. Cutting it would yield huge savings. Then lets not make it calculate the length of the same length lists over an over but instead let's simply provide it like;

```
rotations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
rotations len xs = take len (iterate (\(y:ys) -> ys ++ [y]) xs)
```

Beautiful. Well, now we have to slightly modify our `perms` function accordingly like;

```
perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms []        = [[]]
perms il@(x:xs) = concatMap ((rotations len).(x:)) (perms xs)
                  where len = length il
```

so obviously `il` is now assigned to the **i**nput **l**ist and `len` caches it's length. Now this is beautiful and quite interestingly, compared to the default `Data.List.permutations`, it runs like **1.33 times faster** in GHCI and **3+ times faster** when compiled with -O2.

```
import Data.List

perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms xs = run len xs
           where
           len = length xs

           rotate :: [a] -> [a]
           rotate (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]

           rotations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
           rotations l xs = take l (iterate rotate xs)

           run :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
           run _ []      = [[]]
           run _ [x]     = [[x]]
           run n (x:xs)  = run (n-1) xs >>= rotations n . (x:)
           --run n (x:xs)  = concatMap ((rotations n).(x:)) (run (n-1) xs)

λ> length $ perms [1..13]
6227020800
(302.58 secs, 1,366,730,140,472 bytes)

λ> length $ permutations [1..13]
6227020800
(404.38 secs, 1,800,750,142,384 bytes)
```

The thing is, if you could make the `rotations` function more efficient you can get better results alas i have done some researches but that simple code seems to be as good as it gets in Haskell.

One other important point is, i believe this algorithm is also threadable (havent yet tested that) but it should be since if you check the `run n (x:xs)  = concatMap ((rotations n).(x:)) (run (n-1) xs)` part you may notice that we have a `map` with the `rotations n . (x:)` function over the previous set of permutations. That's exactly the place where i can spawn threads i think.

**Further thoughts... *"Am I really doing the right thing..?"***

I think i am being deceived by the laziness here. I believe doing like `length $ perms [1..12]` does not really enforce the permutations to resolve but just works up until it knows the length of the permutations list which is 12!. I mean the contained values are possibly still thunks.

So instead of `length`, i decided to do like `any (== [11,1,7,2,10,3,8,4,12,5,9,6]) $ perms [1..12]` where `[11,1,7,2,10,3,8,4,12,5,9,6]` is the last permutation element of the `perms` algorithm. So now i guess it shall evaluate all the thunks for an equity check up until it reaches the last element to return a `True`.

When checked like this `perms` and `permutations` with their own last elements, resolve at similar pace (`permutations` being *slightly* faster).

Any ideas are welcome...

Comment: `rotations xs = zipWith const (iterate rotate xs) xs`. (also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49907365/849891), though it's in Common Lisp).

Comment: the CL code relies on surgically modifiable linked list, but it can be coded with arrays by some index juggling, I guess. In Haskell, that'd be done with some STUArray copy of the input list.

Comment: @WillNess That `rotations xs = zipWith const (iterate rotate xs) xs` is a great idea to eliminate `len` and `run` helper function yielding a much simplified and concise code but when benched (compiled with -O or -O2) it is slower. Like 2x slower.

Comment: yeah I had a feeling it might. :)

Comment: @Will Ness I think `length $ perms [1..n]` is not a reasonable performance metric in Haskell. See my ***Further thoughts*** annex above. When tested under those real world circumstances your code seems to work as fine too.

Comment: you could use `filter` instead of `any`, to be sure, independent of the order of the results.

Comment: @Will Ness Still I could not be sure if `any` or `filter` to force all the thunks in the sub arrays (individual permutation) to be resolved since while comparing two lists it only iterates until the first `False` comparison no..? So i tried `all` and `sum` to check their equity in their sum to 78 i.e. `sum [1..12]` which took a little longer but the results do not change as in `perms` and `permutations` almost resolving at the same time. As a side effect though, this interstingly *force*d me to stop being lazy and start reading Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell by Simon Marlow. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think that this is shorter and more elegant variant for what others are suggesting:

```
permutate :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
permutate [] = [[]]
permutate l = [a:x | a <- l, x <- (permutate $ filter (\x -> x /= a) l)]
```

Comment: This only works if there are no duplicates in the input list. For example for input `abb` you would expect output `abb, bab, bba` but this produces `ab, ba`.

Comment: But you can replace `filter ()` by `delete a`.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is better with monads:

```
perm :: [a] -> [[a]]
perm []     = return []
perm (x:xs) = (perm xs) >>= (ins x)
    where
    ins :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
    ins x []     = [[x]]
    ins x (y:ys) = [x:y:ys] ++ ( map (y:) (ins x ys) )
```

So: you have a function, that inserts letter in a word, but it produces more then one word, so how to apply it recursively? `>>=` helps!

Comment: My one is the same idea just the other way round: the helper function takes one list and returns a list of all the ways you can extract one element.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem and then found this discussion. Here is a short solution that uses recursion. The first argument to `doPerm` contains elements eligible for any position in the permutation, the second argument elements that are only eligible for other positions than the first one.

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations xs = doPerm xs []
  where
    doPerm [] _ = [[]]
    doPerm [y] ys = (y:) <$> doPerm ys []
    doPerm (y : ys) zs = doPerm [y] (ys ++ zs) ++ doPerm ys (y : zs)
```

Here is an example run:

```
λ> permutations "abc"
["abc","acb","bca","bac","cba","cab"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's already in the standard [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:permutations) library, so no need to struggle. If you really want to see how to do it, you can look at the source of that library.

Comment: The source of that particular function is *not simple*. Its mechanism is the subject of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484348/what-does-this-list-permutations-implementation-in-haskell-exactly-do), answered by the author of the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
select :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
select = select' id where
  select' _ [] = []
  select' acc (a:r) = (a, acc r) : select' (acc . (a:)) r

permutations [] = [[]]
permutations l = do
  (a,r1) <- select l
  r2 <- permutations r1
  return (a: r2)
```