# Rotating a list in Haskell with all posibilities

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

How can I edit the following code to make Haskell show all the possibilities of rotating an input list from the user :

```
rotate ::  Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate n text = take (length text) (drop n (cycle text))
```

I assume that to print all the possibilities we need to drop the first element X times. where X is the length of the list entered.

```
circle ::  [a] -> [[a]]
circle text = take (length text) (drop (1) (cycle text))
```

I can't perform the operation where the list is printed X times. Also I have errors while running the above code which states the following:  **Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’**

I wanted the Output to be something like that:

```
circle "ab"
["ab","ba"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all permutations of a list in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097116/get-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-haskell)

Comment: What if the string is `"abab"`, should that result in `["abab", "baba"]`, or `["abab", "baba", "abab", "baba"]`?

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid any calls to `length`, as well as the repeated calls to `cycle` and ever-larger arguments to `drop`, by instead zipping any otherwise-infinite lists against the finite input list, to trim them to be the size you expect, discarding later elements:

```
circle xs = let trim ys = zipWith const ys xs
            in trim . map trim . iterate tail . cycle $ xs

*Main> circle "abc"
["abc","bca","cab"]
```

Comment: Use `tails` instead of `iterate tail`. The former doesn't rely on an infinite argument to produce fully-defined results.

Comment: @dfeuer I considered this, but I didn't really want to add an import, and the argument is guaranteed to be infinite.

Comment: `iterate (drop 1)`?

Comment: I'm perfectly happy to use `tali` in cases where the list is locally known to be non-empty and pattern-matching would be inconvenient. Until `tail` is removed from the Prelude, I don't want to use weird stuff like `drop 1` to avoid it in the cases it's perfect for.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're interested in all permutations of all permutations. It means that you're dealing with a `[ [] ]` - list of list (recall that `"ab"` is just `['a', 'b']`). `Data.List` has what you need. [Source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:permutations). Otherwise, I've completely misunderstood your intention.

Comment: Rotations are not the same as permutations. For example given "abc", the rotations are "abc", "bca", and "cab". Note that "bac" isn't in this list, even though it is a valid permutation.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reusing the `rotate` function and apply some recursion:

```
circle text = text : (circle $ rotate text)
```

Now this produces an infinite list. If you only want each rotation once, then use `take`:

```
circle text = take (length text) $ text : (circle $ rotate text)
```

This version has the disadvantage of calculating the length of `text` each time you call `circle`. Instead, you could use a helper function with a counter that decrements for each recursion:

```
circle = circle' (length text)
  where circle' 0 _ = []
        circle' n text = text : (circle' (rotate text) (n - 1))
```